# Finding work done on a spring using Hooke's law(force = constant * distance) and Work equation (work = force * distance)

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I've tried:
equating work to force * change in distance $(4 = f(x) * \Delta x$), finding $f(x) = \frac{2}{7}$

Then use hooke'ss law to find the spring's constant:
$\frac{2}{7} = k * 14\implies k=\frac{1}{49}$

Thus: Force = $f(x) = \frac {x}{49}$

$\int_{0}^{20} \frac{x}{49}dx = \frac{200}{49}$ which is incorrect.

Can someone tell me what I've done wrong, where my knowledge gap is..?

[image]

Comment: $W=F*d$ only when the force is a constant, here you cant pull a spring using a constant force so you have to keep on increasing the applied force

Comment: This may be a question for the [physics stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Incase this inevitably gets deleted i suggest looking up the answer by [Floris](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/127006/266713) on this same topic

Comment: @AdilMohammed, thanks I saw that and is aligned with what is taught for this question. However i tried the other way too, getting the $k = \frac{4}{14}$ then integrate with $\int_{0}^{20} \frac{4}{14} x dx =\frac{400}{7}$ which is also incorrect. Why..?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Work done is stored as Potential Energy for any spring constant $k$

Hooke's Law

$$F = k \cdot x $$

Potential energy stored due to *varying force*

$$ PE=\frac12 F\cdot x $$

Plug in

$$ PE= \frac{k x^2}{2}= \text{Area under (F-x) line}$$
[image]